# Use smali code in java console application

Tags: java, android, smali

At first I decompiled `file.apk` to `smali` files using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/). Next I found interesting method and copied it:

```
.method private compressAndFormat([B)J
    .locals 10
    .param p1, "userData"    # [B

    .prologue
    const/4 v9, 0x1

    // REST OF CODE
.end method
```

I wanted to use this method in my application, so I created new project with method called `private long compressAndFormat(byte[] userData)`, decompiled that project to `small` and replaced content of newly created method with the same method from original `small` files, and compiled to `apk`.

And it worked! Unfortunately, after every change I made in my application I had to decompile it to `small`, replace `compressAndFormat` method content and compile it to `apk`.

Now I would like to create java console application with `compressAndFormat` method. Is there any way to do this? I was thinking about something like this:

1. Decompile file.apk to file.smali
2. Decompile file.smali to file.dex
3. Decompile new_file.jar to new_file.dex
4. Copy method from file.dex to new_file.dex
5. Compile new_file.dex to new_file.jar

What do you think about that?

Comment: Your only other option is to rewrite your smali code to java again, which must not be hard if it's not obfuscated. There is no other way then decompiling both apps and tweaking the smali files.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to copy the smali code to your Java
Did you tried https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar ?
Using this tool you can convert the dex back to Java (in most of the cases)